# Determine array index

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

I have the following loop in a C code:

```
int f[10],b[10],k=0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    k = b[i+3]*f[i+2]; //please ignore the out of bound problem
}
```

I want to determine that the array b has a stride of 3 and f has increment factor of 2 in the above code.

The generated LLVM assembly is(for the block containing loop):

```
;<label>:12
%13 = load i32* %i, align 4
%14 = icmp slt i32 %13, 10
br i1 %14, label %15, label %30

;<label>:15                         ;preds=%12
%16 = load i32* %i, align 4
%17 = add nsw i32 %16,**3** // this is the increment value
%18 = sext i32 %17 to i64
**%19 = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i32]* %b, i32 0, i64 % 18**
%20 = load i32* % 19, align 4
%21 = load i32* %i, align 4
%22 = add nsw i32 %21,**2** // this is the increment value
%23 = sext i32 %22 to i64
**%24 = getelementptr invounds[10xi32]* %f, i32 0, i64 %23**
%25 = load i32* %24, align 4
%26 = mul nsw i32 %20, %25
store i32 %26, i32* %k, align 4
br label %27

;<label>:27
%28 = load i32* %l, align 4
%29 = add nsw i32 %28,1
store i32 %29, i32* %i, align 4
br label %12
```

Now in my LoopPass, I use the following code:

```
Value *f = gep->getOperand(3);
if(dyn_cast<llvm::ConstantInt>(f))
{
    errs()<<(dyn_cast<llvm::ConstantInt>(f))->getValue();
   // the output should be 3 and 2 respectively

}
```

But I don't get anything as output. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: If you use the term stride, I would have expected `i+3` to be `i*3` (similarly, `i+2` -> `i*2`)

Comment: Also, the generated IR does not appear to have any loop.

Comment: @CAFxX Now I have included the entire assembly for the loop. Also I have changed stride to increment factor.

Comment: @CAFxX infact, even if it is possible to get the stride (2 in i*2), it would also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the proper way to get an integer from a `ConstantInt` instance is via `getSExtValue()`, not `getValue()`; and it's best if you also make sure you can handle the returned value, so:

```
assert (CI->getBitWidth() <= 32);
int x = CI->getSExtValue();
```

Secondly, just getting the value passed as the 3rd operand to the GEP will not get you a `ConstantInt`, it will get you a pointer to the `sext` instruction! If you want to find the actual constant, you have to traverse the graph all the way back until you find the `add` instruction, then identify the constant as one of its operands.

Finally, it seems you are looking for offsets, not steps; but if you *are* looking for steps, consider using Scalar Evolution, which has mechanisms you might find useful, such as:

```
/// getStepRecurrence - This method constructs and returns the recurrence
/// indicating how much this expression steps by.  If this is a polynomial
/// of degree N, it returns a chrec of degree N-1.
/// We cannot determine whether the step recurrence has self-wraparound.
const SCEV *getStepRecurrence(ScalarEvolution &SE) const
```

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to detect the existence of third argument i.e. in case the array is b[i] ? Also can I generalize it like: If there is a 3rd argument in getelementprtinst and it is an array then move back until I find an add instruction. Then extract the 2nd operand term from there?

Comment: or would it be ok to move back two instructions ? (since add is followed by sext followed by getElementPtrInstr)

Comment: @krammer regarding moving back two instructions - you can try, but I have a feeling it would be flaky. I'd think it's better to try and generalize it. And you can of course use methods such as `getNumIndices()`, `isa<>`, etc. to identify this case.